# Pandas\Python: How to count the number of last identical values ​in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is pandas data frame.
Column 'Direction' consists only 3 variant values: Down, Flat or Up.
Only the last identical values ​​matter. So, question is in title.

```
     Time     Direction
id
0    16:59    Up
1    17:00    Flat
2    17:01    Up
3    17:02    Down
4    17:03    Down
5    17:04    Up
6    17:05    Up
7    17:06    Up
```

Let's say data frame name is panda. Result must be something like that (And this one much prefer):

```
result = 0
result = panda.tail(?)['Direction'].count_last_values(#as the most last value[Up <- in this case])[0]
print(result)
3
```

Or like that:

```
     Time     Direction     Series
id
0    16:59    Up            1
1    17:00    Flat          0
2    17:01    Up            1
3    17:02    Down          1
4    17:03    Down          2
5    17:04    Up            1
6    17:05    Up            2
7    17:06    Up            3
```

By myself I can do this (but I want something simpler):

```
import pandas as pd

panda = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['16:59','17:00','17:01','17:02','17:03','17:04','17:05','17:06'], 'Direction':['Up','Flat','Up','Down','Down','Up','Up','Up']})

    Time    Direction
0   16:59   Up
1   17:00   Flat
2   17:01   Up
3   17:02   Down
4   17:03   Down
5   17:04   Up
6   17:05   Up
7   17:06   Up

tail = panda.tail(1)['Direction'].iloc[0]
counter = 0 
i = len(panda) - 1
if tail != 'Flat':
    while tail==panda.iloc[i]['Direction']:
        i -= 1
        counter += 1
print(counter)

3
```

Comment: What happens when the last value is 'Flat'? And why he is zero in id 1?

Comment: 1. If last value is  'Flat' counter become the same (counter = 0). It's no matter. 2. 
Because it does not count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if the current value is the same as the previous one with `shift` and create 'groups' with `cumsum()`. Create the new column using `.groupby` and `cumcount`.

```
s = (df['Direction'] != df['Direction'].shift()).cumsum()
df['Series'] = df.groupby(s).cumcount()+1

#output:
    Time    Direction   Series
id          
0   16:59   Up          1
1   17:00   Flat        1
2   17:01   Up          1
3   17:02   Down        1
4   17:03   Down        2
5   17:04   Up          1
6   17:05   Up          2
7   17:06   Up          3
```

If you need to count from zero when the **Direction** column is 'Flat', use `.loc`

```
df.loc[df['Direction'] == 'Flat', 'Series'] = df['Series'].subtract(1)

#output
    Time    Direction   Series
id          
0   16:59   Up          1     
1   17:00   Flat        0
2   17:01   Up          1
3   17:02   Down        1
4   17:03   Down        2
5   17:04   Up          1
6   17:05   Up          2
7   17:06   Up          3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
panda = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['16:59','17:00','17:01','17:02','17:03','17:04','17:05','17:06'], 'Direction':['Up','Flat','Up','Down','Down','Up','Up','Up']})
print(panda)
counter = 0
tail = panda.iloc[-1]['Direction']
for i in range(len(panda)-1,0,-1):
    if panda.iloc[i]['Direction'] == tail:
        counter += 1
    else:
        break
print(counter)
```